# No overload for method Add taking three arguments

Tags: asp.net

```
public class Class1
{
    public Class1(int id , string name , string cast)
    {

        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.cast = cast;

    }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string cast { get; set; }

}


 public List<Class1> getall() {

        List<Class1> list = new List<Class1>();
        using  (SqlConnection con = Main.Maindata2()){
            SqlCommand cmd
                 = new SqlCommand("SELECT  * FROM  List", con);

            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader reaader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reaader.Read()) { 
           // list.Add((int)reaader["Id"],(string)reaader["name"],(string)reaader["cast"]);

//list.CLAS
            list.Add((int)reaader["Id"],  (string)reaader["name"], (string)reaader["cast"]);


            }
            return list;
        }

    }
    }
```

Comment: every thing is ok but still getting error

Comment: Error 1 No overload for method 'Add' takes 3 arguments

Comment: list.Add takes an object. You need to create an object of Class1 and initialize with id, name and cast. Then you pass that object to list.Add(object)

Answer (score 1):

you need to do this within while loop

```
var obj = new Class1((int)reaader["Id"].ToString(), reaader["name"].ToString(), reaader["cast"].ToString());
list.Add(obj);
```